# Python selenium send_keys() escape forward slash in URL

Tags: python, selenium

I trying to send a URL with Selenium `send_keys(url)`
For example, the URL parsed to the script is `https://www.test.com/downloads/myfile.zip`

URL sent by selenium to my application then become `https:www.test.comdownloadsmyfile.zip`

i tried `url.replace('/', '\/')` and `url.replace('/', '\\/')`, but still not getting the correct URL.

Comment: Just added the below answer - I'm assuming you're sending your keys to a input field in the DOM?  - you use `driver.get(url)` to navigate pages and if it's not an input field it might not work as you expect

Answer (score 0):

`send_keys` works fine with forward slashes - chances are this is specific to your application or your input data.

This is some sample code as a demo:

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome() # note i modified this to my driver
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

url = "https://www.duckduckgo.co.uk"
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "search_form_input_homepage").send_keys(url)
```

This is what you see - complete with forward slashes:

[image: duck with slash]

###########################

An alternative way to set a value is to use JS. Try this approach:

```py
url = "https://www.duckduckgo.co.uk" 
driver.get(url)
element= driver.find_element(By.ID, "search_form_input_homepage")#.send_keys(url)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value=arguments[1]", element, url)
```

If the above samples work for you on duckduckgo - that suggest it's your application or your data, and not your machine/selenium/version.

What you can try next is to rule out your input data and find the boundaries of the issue.
Try a hard coded `.send_keys('/')`.

- If that works, you know its your input data.
- If that fails, you know it's your application

Try a print on your data.

- If that has salshes after it's parsed into your test, it's something else

Beyond that - please share more code and more information around the issue.

Comment: I’m facing similar issue, tried all your above approaches, the particular input field i’m trying to fill is giving this issue. When i try to send URL to another input field like, the username, its showing correct value. And when i tried the JS approach, no input is being made even with normal strings. Any suggestions please?